# Matplotlib - How to make the marker face color transparent without making the line transparent

Tags: python, matplotlib

I know how to set the transparency of a line in matplotlib. For example, the following code makes the line and the markers transparent.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

vec = np.random.uniform(0, 10, 50)
f = plt.figure(1)
ax = f.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(vec, color='#999999', marker='s', alpha=0.5)
```

I want line's alpha=1.0, and marker's face color to be semi-transparent (alpha=0.5). Can this be done in matplotlib?

Comment: Can you plot it twice, once with a solid line and once with transparent markers?

Comment: Just after I asked the question, I thought about that. Yes, that would definitely work, unless there is a better option to set which achieves this.

Comment: @mgilson Sorry, that actually does not work. Since that creates problems when creating legends. The lines in the legends have no markers in that case.

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html#legend-handler

Answer (score 79, accepted):

### See @Pelson's answer below for the correct way to do this with one line.

You can do this in a hacky way by sticky taping together two independent `Line2D` objects.

```
th = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 64)
y = np.sin(th)
ax = plt.gca()

lin, = ax.plot(th, y, lw=5)
mark, = ax.plot(th, y, marker='o', alpha=.5, ms=10)

ax.legend([(lin, mark)], ['merged'])
plt.draw()
```

[image: demo figure]

[see here](http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html#legend-handler) for explanation

Comment: Nice answer. I particularly liked the illustration of how to handle the legend.

Comment: @pelson Can you say anything about how the rendering constraints?  I only dug down into the AGG code once, in a very limited way.

Comment: It turns out you can do this. I'll post an answer now.

Comment: Thanks, this is a neat way to create legends when markers are drawn separately.

Answer (score 56):

After reading the source code of `matplotlib.line`, it turns out there is a code path (at least in Agg, but probably all backends) which allows you to do this. Whether this was ever intentional behaviour, I'm not sure, but it certainly works at the moment. The key is *not* to define an alpha value for the line, but to define the colours desired along with an alpha value:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([0, 1], [1, 0], 'k')
# Do not set an alpha value here
l, = plt.plot(range(10), 'o-', lw=10, markersize=30)

l.set_markerfacecolor((1, 1, 0, 0.5))
l.set_color('blue')

plt.show()
```

These can also be given as arguments in `plt.plot` (at least in matplotlib version 3.6.3), so just

```
plt.plot(range(10), 'bo-', markerfacecolor=(1, 1, 0, 0.5), )
```

will do the trick.

HTH

Comment: This is useful if you want to have a different alpha for the marker face and marker edge, which should be a common thing to do (hint hint).

Comment: Thanks, very useful together with [`matplotlib.colors.to_rgba`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.to_rgba.html#matplotlib-colors-to-rgba). E.g. `plt.plot(range(10), 'bo-', markeredgecolor='b', markerfacecolor=colors.to_rgba('b', 0.5))`.