# Transparent markerfacecolor in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to plot a bunch of markers (one at a time) that have a semi-transparent face color and an opaque (alpha=1) edge color using Matplotlib.  This seemed straight forward by set each in the plot command using the appropriate rgba values (like it was suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15936516) answer), but it's not working
Sample Code (Updated from original post to better illustrate the issue):

```
N = 48
xys = np.random.rand(N,2)
markers = []
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
for i in range(N):
    m = ax.plot(
        xys[i,0], xys[i,1],
        linestyle='None', marker='o', markersize=20,
        markeredgewidth=4, markeredgecolor=(0, 0, 0, 1.0),
        markerfacecolor=(1, 0, 0.2, 0.1),
    )[0]
ax.grid()
ax.set_axisbelow(True)
fig.savefig('scratch_fig.png', dpi=300)
```

That gives me this plot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVaBU.jpg

As you can see the edges are correct, solid black.  But, when you look at the markers that are overlapping each other and the grid you can see that they are not semi-transparent.

I produced this result using Matplotlib 1.2.1 on both Windows 7 and Ubuntu

Does anyone know how to fix this, without creating two sets of overlapping markers?

Comment: This seems to work for me.  What version of matplotlib are you using?  (I'm using trunk and can't conveniently downgrade to compare.)

Comment: Hmm.  Maybe it was recently fixed, then: I see [this](http://imgur.com/aZovETn).

Comment: @DSM , what version of matplotlib are you using?  (1.2.1 is the newest stable release)  Also, can you try the slight modified code I put up?  I think the plot you're getting has semi-transparent edges, but that will be easier to see with the new example code.  BTW, thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm using the current development version, so it's post-1.2.1.  Your new code gives me [this](http://imgur.com/pvQiZWW), which looks very different from yours.

Comment: Ok, thanks @DSM .  Well, it seems that the developmental version is making both the edge and the face take on the alpha value of the face.  Strange.

Comment: @dsm Did either of you report this as a bug?

Comment: You can also try something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15928539/matplotlib-how-to-make-the-marker-face-color-transparent-without-making-the-li/15931575#15931575 It is hacky, but it works

Comment: @tcaswell I have not reported it (I'm not familiar with how that's done)

Comment: go to: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues?state=open  You will need to register with github, then click 'new issue', and then give this code and both the image you get + the one @DSM gets, and the version you are using.  If you find this onerous or really don't want to sign up for github I can do it.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the instructions @tcaswell.  I will submit an error report on this.