# matplotlib legend: Including markers and lines from two different graphs in one line

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I've been doing some linear regression and want to plot the markers (original data) and the lines (regression) on the same line in the legend. For simplicity, here's a fake regression:

```
from pylab import *
ax = subplot(1,1,1)
p1, = ax.plot([1,2,3,4,5,6],'r-', label="line 1")
p2, = ax.plot([6,5,4,3,2,1],'b-', label="line 2")

p3, = ax.plot([1.2,1.8,3.1,4.1,4.8,5.9],'ro', label="dots 1")
p4, = ax.plot([6.1,5.1,3.8,3.1,1.9,0.9],'bo', label="dots 2")

ax.legend(loc='center right',numpoints=1)
show()
```

So I want the legend to consist of 2 lines, each showing a line and a dot, instead of 4 lines. How can I do that?

Answer (score 6):

You just need to use `legend` a bit more directly.  See [Matplotlib - How to make the marker face color transparent without making the line transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15928539/matplotlib-how-to-make-the-marker-face-color-transparent-without-making-the-li/15931575#15931575) and [user guide](http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html#legend-handler).

```
ax.legend([(p1, p3), (p2, p4)], ['set 1', 'set 2'])
plt.draw()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just try with

```
from pylab import *
ax = subplot(1,1,1)
p1, = ax.plot([1,2,3,4,5,6],'r-')
p2, = ax.plot([6,5,4,3,2,1],'b-')

p3, = ax.plot([1.2,1.8,3.1,4.1,4.8,5.9],'r-o', label="dots 1")
p4, = ax.plot([6.1,5.1,3.8,3.1,1.9,0.9],'b-o', label="dots 2")

ax.legend(loc='center right',numpoints=1)
show()
```

or if you want a poor man's solution, you can plot something outside your plotting range and label only that plot.
For instance

```
p5 = ax.plot(ones(2)*1e6,ones(2)*1e6,'r-o', label="dots 1")
```

do the same for the other label and then force your plot not to include `p5`, for example, like this

```
ax.set_xlim(0,10);ax.set_ylim(0,10)
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually solve this problem by creating dummy lines with the plot properties that I am interested in showing. However, I think @tcaswell's solution is better.

```
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D

def create_dummy_line(**kwds):
    return Line2D([], [], **kwds)

# your code here

# Create the legend
lines = [
    ('name A', {'color': 'red', 'linestyle': '-', 'marker': 'o'}),
    ('name B', {'color': 'blue', 'linestyle': '-', 'marker': 'o'}),
]
ax.legend(
    # Line handles
    [create_dummy_line(**l[1]) for l in lines],
    # Line titles
    [l[0] for l in lines],
    loc='center right'
)
```